# How to run django app in allen NLP environment?

Tags: django, python-3.x, allennlp

I have created an API in Django. It is supposed to take a request and pass the argument to allenNLP files to gather a computed response. I want to know how to run my django app in allenNLP environment and I want all the source code of allenNLP to be in a folder in my django project. Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is running AllenNLP inside django. 
You can add AllenNLP libraries in your requirements.py. Next, the .py file can be stored in any of your source code hierarchy.

In your views.py, where you are getting request and extracting parameters, you can call the .py file which contains allennlp source code.

Not sure about what AllenNLP files you're talking about, if it's code files, they can go in your regular source code folder, if it's a static files, like Image, CSV etc, they need to go in static folder.

Please clar my understanding of your requirement if the answer doesn't address your question.

Comment: AllenNLP files are codes which happen to perform some particular functions. https://github.com/allenai/allennlp 

I will try it. Thanks a lot. :)